# Tree Map conversion to custom arraylist

Tags: arraylist, treemap

how to convert the following tree map

```
TreeMap tm = new TreeMap();
  tm.put("apple", 90));
  tm.put("Lg", 45);
  tm.put("Samsung",80);
  tm.put("Nokia",49);
  tm.put("Motorola",43);
```

to Array list 
 whose contents will be

`{apple=90,lg=45,samsung=80,nokia=49,motorola=43}`

Iam using Java JDK 1.4

Thanks in advance.

Prasad

Comment: An Array list doesn't store value=pair couples

Comment: @Anto not correct, depends what language he's using, on php or on javascript it does!

Comment: What language are you using? Java, C#, C, JavaScript or other?